# How does $\frac{p}{\sqrt{kp - p^2}}$ become $-\frac12 \left( \frac{k-2p}{\sqrt{kp - p^2}} - \frac{k}{\sqrt{kp - p^2}}\right)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, fractions

This is a trivial question, but could someone explain how
$$\frac{p}{\sqrt{kp - p^2}}$$
was expanded to the following?
$$-\frac12 \left( \frac{k-2p}{\sqrt{kp - p^2}} - \frac{k}{\sqrt{kp - p^2}}\right)$$

Comment: Did you had tried? Really?

Comment: Simplify the second expression and see that it reduces to the first.

Comment: @AndreasBlass yes, thank you. However, I already did that to see if it would help me understand what methodology is used to expand the expression.

Comment: The author needed the more complicated expression in order to perform the next step (not shown in your Question). It's like spring-cleaning a room where you may need to first unpack stuff and create a slight mess *before* things become more streamlined than originally. There is no special methodology to expand the expression; the author was (working backwards and) being guided by what the next step requires.